# INSERT INTO from SELECT in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am doing an insert into from select in MySQL, is it different for MariaDB?

My syntax looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO catalog_product_index_price (entity_type_id,attribute_id,store_id,entity_id,value) VALUES (
SELECT entity_type_id,attribute_id,store_id,entity_id,value FROM (
    SELECT 4 as entity_type_id, 456 as attribute_id, 0 as store_id, catalog_product_link.product_id as entity_id, catalog_product_index_price.min_price as value
    FROM catalog_product_index_price
    JOIN catalog_product_link ON catalog_product_link.linked_product_id = catalog_product_index_price.entity_id
    WHERE catalog_product_link.link_type_id IN (
        SELECT link_type_id
        FROM catalog_product_link_type
        WHERE code LIKE 'custom_%'
    )
    GROUP BY catalog_product_link.product_id
    ORDER BY catalog_product_index_price.min_price
) as from_price_table);
```

and I get the error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2`

Comment: There is no `VALUES` in the syntax of the [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) statement.

Comment: lol how stupid of me, thanks.

Comment: Does this really work in MySQL? How did you test it?